# Registration date and domain transfer

Tags: domain

I want to buy a domain from someone (domain transfer) before expiration. Does the registration date (in whois) will be renewed? I want the date not to be renewed, so that it looks like an old website.

Comment: This may help: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100752/domain-name-registered-on-date

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I want the transfer to take place BEFORE expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". Registrars can do what they like with the dates of domains under their control. Most likely the original registration date will be maintained but you won't know until you complete the transfer. You likely have no control over this either way.